# String has a line break at the end (for no reason) in C#

Tags: c#

I'm currently writing an application in .NET which reads from a file - in that file, there is a path to another file written. The application then prints the content of that file.
This is an example:

File 1:

```
D:\Path\To\My\File.txt

SOME OTHER STUFF
```

File 2:

```
Hello, world!
```

When I run my application, it throws an error saying the syntax of the path is invalid. I tried seeing the actual string it takes from File 1, so I did this:

```
string testString = File.ReadAllText(file); // file is a variable that's already created, which is just a string with the path of File 1.
File.WriteAllText("test.txt", $"'{testString}'");
```

I looked into the newly created `test.txt` and saw this.

```
'D:\Path\To\My\File.txt
'
```

Why is there a line break before the second quote? I tried googling this with no success. Please help me with this, I am new to C#.

## Edit 1:

I tried using `File.ReadAllBytes()`, but the results were the same.

This is the outcome:

```
'D:\Georges\Desktop\G\test2.g
'
```

And this is my code:

```
byte[] testString = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
File.WriteAllBytes("test.txt", testString);
```

## Edit 2:

When I deleted everything from the file EXCEPT that one line, it worked. That's good, but I do want to be able to add more lines to my file without it not working.

Comment: And there was no line break in File1? You have looked that up?

Comment: Yes, I checked.

Comment: @zenof When you use `File.ReadAllBytes()` and output the individual bytes, what is the output you get? Please [edit] your question to include the code you use for `File.ReadAllBytes()` and the byte values you get when you read the file.

Comment: It's very common for text file to end with a new line and for some editors to not actually display it.  So how did you check that it did not end with a newline?

Comment: try loading the file into a hex editor

Comment: @juharr I split every line in the file by \n, so there's no line break left in the array.

Comment: @zenof Output the `testString` `byte` array with a `for()` loop, by showing the loop variable `i`, the actual byte value `testString[i]` and the value of that byte value casted to `char`. That way you can see each individual byte from the file. Please [edit] your question to include the `for` loop you are used and the output you get when executed.

Comment: Consider using the File.ReadAllLines function1

Answer (score 1):

maybe you should use [`File.ReadLines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines?view=net-5.0) instead of `File.ReadAllText`. something like this:

```
string testString = File.ReadLines(file).ToList()[0]; // file is a variable that's already created, which is just a string with the path of File 1.
File.WriteAllText("test.txt", $"'{testString}'");
```

Comment: Might as well just do `ReadAllLines(file)[0]`,  or `ReadLines(file).First()` to avoid reading more than the first line.

Comment: @juharr `ReadAllLines` reads into an array, bypassing the advantage. `ReadLines` is definitely the way forward if this is a concern.

Comment: @ClickRick If by advantage you mean not reading the entire file, then that's exactly what I was getting at.  Though given that this file seems to have only 1 or 2 lines I don't think that really matters.

Comment: @juharr In my example I only wrote 1 line (so you wouldn't be confused and think that those other lines should be included in the string), but the file actually has multiple lines.

Answer (score 1):

You don't show your code, so I cannot be sure this is your problem, but from experience, it looks like it is.. 
Your filename probably has an unseen character inside at the end of it, so when you copy-paste the filename into the text-file you also copied it with that special character. 
As some special characters are unseen the counter-intuitive thing that happens here is that you don't expect your file-name that looks to you like 'test2.g' to actually contain 'test2.g'+chr(13) - where char-13 is i.e. a linefeed character.